# How can I transfer 2D array to 1D array without using Loop in C?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, 2d, transfer

I have two arrays: one 2D, arr, the other 1D, ar, for example like this :
`int arr[1][18]; int ar[18];`
I want to copy arr[1][18] to ar[18] ""without using loop"". How can I do this?
I would appreciate if someone could explain this.
Thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: `memcpy`. Of course it uses a loop internally for that large a copy.

Comment: Also, you probably mean you want to copy `arr[0]` to `ar` (as both are 18 element arrays of `int`).

Comment: `int arr[1][18];` declares a 2D array in which the outer array only has a single element. Is that really what you want? See my answer for an example of a 2D array which has several elements in the outer array.

Comment: Depending on your actual requirements, another possibility is to change `int ar[18];` to `int *ar;`.  Then you can just say `ar = arr[0];`.  (But in this case you're not making a copy.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a loop, you can use the function `memcpy` instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    //declare and initialize the 2D array
    int arr_2D[2][18] = {
        {  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 },
        { 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36 }
    };

    //declare the 1D array
    int arr_1D[18];

    //copy arr_2D[1] to arr_1D (without a loop)
    memcpy( arr_1D, arr_2D[1], sizeof *arr_2D );

    //print the result of the copy (in a loop)
    for ( int i = 0; i < 18; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", arr_1D[i] );
    }
    printf( "\n" );
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
```

As you can see, `arr_2D[1]` was successfully copied to `arr_1D` without a loop. A loop was only used for printing the result.

However, it is worth noting that `memcpy` is most likely using some kind of loop internally. Therefore, even if the code does not have a loop, you are still technically using a loop. There is no way to solve this problem without some kind loop, except by unrolling the loop, like this:

```
arr_1D[0]  = arr_2D[1][0];
arr_1D[1]  = arr_2D[1][1];
arr_1D[2]  = arr_2D[1][2];
arr_1D[3]  = arr_2D[1][3];
arr_1D[4]  = arr_2D[1][4];
arr_1D[5]  = arr_2D[1][5];
arr_1D[6]  = arr_2D[1][6];
arr_1D[7]  = arr_2D[1][7];
arr_1D[8]  = arr_2D[1][8];
arr_1D[9]  = arr_2D[1][9];
arr_1D[10] = arr_2D[1][10];
arr_1D[11] = arr_2D[1][11];
arr_1D[12] = arr_2D[1][12];
arr_1D[13] = arr_2D[1][13];
arr_1D[14] = arr_2D[1][14];
arr_1D[15] = arr_2D[1][15];
arr_1D[16] = arr_2D[1][16];
arr_1D[17] = arr_2D[1][17];
```

Comment: What do you believe `memcpy` does?

Comment: @Blindy: Yes, you are correct that `memcpy` most likely also uses a loop internally. I have edited my answer to mention this.